# How to access a text service from an Applescript?

Tags: macos, service, applescript

If an application exposes a Text Service (for example, one that would normally paste the time of day inside the text field of an application such as TextEdit), how to programmatically access this service from an Applescript and capture this text in a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, there would have to be an entry in the Dictionary to give access to any function. If there is a function that isn't made available then there is GUI scripting, scripting the actual mouse and keyboard clicks to get to something in the menu system, but that there are many new issues that will have to be worked around. There is an excellent starter tutorial here: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html